# Geometry nodes, selecting random edge per island

Tags: geometry-nodes

with this node setup, I can select **one edge per island**, the problem is I don't know **how to define or randomize the selected edge.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select a random edge per mesh island, all you have to do is count the number of edges per mesh island, generate a random value between $0$ and $Edge Count -1$ and compare this with the edge index per mesh island.

Something like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 4.0.2+)*</sub>

...or even more simplified:

[image]